# Shiro Annotations are not scanned

Tags: tomcat, aspectj, shiro

I am new to shiro, in eclipse, I created a dynamic web project, in which I used to test login, logout, authorization, .... features of shiro using tomcat server, now I want to experiment using the annotation @RequiredRoles for authorization, for this I installed the plugin AJDT to enable AspectJ, and converted my project, so that it has the AOP feature, I added the aspect aspect org.apache.shiro.aspectj.ShiroAnnotationAuthorizingAspectfollowing to aop.xml under META-INF
but nothing is working, from a web form I try to call a servlet which tries to access a method in a certain class, this method is annotated with the @RequiredRoles annotation, although the logged in person is not authorized , he still can call the method!!! 
I feel like if I miss something especially that I am new to both,shiro and aspectj, highly appreciate any enlightenment

Comment: I think the problem is that the aop.xml file is not seen or even considered, i have tried to include the source code of org.apache.shiro.aspectj.ShiroAnnotationAuthorizingAspectfollowing and everything works well, even without the aop.xml, can anyone tell me how can i call an aspect from an external jar?

Comment: I have never used Shiro and do not even know what it is good for, but when I looked at the [AspectJ sample project](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/shiro/trunk/samples/aspectj/) provided as part of the documentation, I saw that the Maven build uses the AspectJ Maven plugin, i.e. it uses compile-time weaving (CTW) rather than load-time weaving (LTW). Because *aop.xml* is only used for LTW, your assumption that it is missing seems to be wrong. This is StackOverflow. Please post some code, ideally an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), in order to help us in helping you.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I am trying to use an already pre compiled aspect provided by shiro implementation, according to my decent knowledge in both Aspectj and shiro, Iwill need LTW. i have tried to include the source of aspect in my project, and everything works fine, my problem is that when i need to link my code to an external aspect. i feel like if the problem is wiht telling tomcat to use LTW

Comment: Then you compiled your aspect separately and weaved it into your Java classes via LTW. Fine. How can I know? You did not post any code or configuration details, just plain prose. This way you made your question a quiz rather than something I could analyse. Sorry for guessing wrong under these circumstances. P.S.: If you have decent AspectJ knowledge, how come you forgot to specify the weaving agent on the command line? ;-)

Comment: the aspect is already precompiled, i already said that it is from an external jar, and sorry i meant Modest not Decent,  i have already mentioned in my post that i am new to both Aspectj and shiro. Anyways, thanks alot for trying to help me:)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by adding the following line to *catalina.bat*:

```
SET JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -javaagent:"C:\Apatche\apache-tomcat-7.0.47\lib\aspectjweaver-1.7.4.jar"
```

Comment: Well, if you use LTW and specify no weaving agent, it cannot work. See my comment about the quiz situation above. BTW, you can accept your own answer here, even though I would rather suggest to delete the question altogether.

Comment: Remove the question!!!, you said that you never used shiro, and i have seen my problem "integrating shiro with Aspectj" in many places where no answer where supplied, please don't assume the knowledge you have to exist with everyone. thansk again

Comment: As I said, it was a suggestion. You are not obliged to follow it. :-) But then please close the question by accepting your own answer.